# Rails - ActiveAdmin - Can't get associated modal attribute to show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using ActiveAdmin and have an Account model and a User model. Each account will have a has_many relationship with users, and I'd like to be able to list the user names on the account table.

I've seen quite a few SO questions that address the same question and this is how far I've managed to get:

```
  index do
    column :id
    column :account_status
    column :users do |account|
      account.users.each do |user|
        auto_link user
      end
    end
    column :address do |account|
      account.address
    end
    column :created_at
    column :updated_at
    actions
  end
```

Note: i've also tried replacing "auto_link user" with "user.name"

This kind of works. It does get the data, but instead of showing attribute values I seem to just get a memory address reference:

[image: How the Account column looks]

I should say here that I am quite new to both Ruby and Rails, so it is likely that I am just missing the point. Considering what I have, is there something I've missed out?

Answer (score 1):

`account.users.each` will return an array of User objects. That's why you got something like "a memory address reference". To return a list of `user.name`, you should do something like this:

```
column :users do |account|
  account.users.pluck(:name).join(', ')
end
```

I use `join` here to convert an array of names to a string. I'm not sure without `join`, what will be displayed. You can try it by yourself :)